# NLTK is not working in docker

Tags: docker, nltk, docker-compose

I want to run a nltk service in docker. However I always get the error message "'nltk' is not a package". Are you able to figure out what is going wrong? During build everything works fine, the nltk version is printed. When starting the container with `docker-compose up nltk` I get

> $ docker-compose up nltk

```
Recreating nltk
Attaching to nltk
nltk          | Traceback (most recent call last):
nltk          |   File "/var/www/nltk.py", line 1, in <module>
nltk          |     from nltk.corpus import brown
nltk          |   File "/var/www/nltk.py", line 1, in <module>
nltk          |     from nltk.corpus import brown
nltk          | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk.corpus'; 'nltk' is not a package
```

> docker-compose.yml

```
nltk:
    build: docker/nltk
    container_name: nltk
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/nltk/var/www/nltk.py:/var/www/nltk.py
    environment:
      HOME: /var/www
```

> Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN mkdir /var/www
ENV HOME /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN pip install -U nltk
RUN pip install -U numpy
RUN python -m nltk.downloader -d $HOME/nltk_data all
RUN python -c "import nltk"
RUN python -c "import nltk; print(nltk.__version__)"

EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "python", "/var/www/nltk.py" ]
```

> nltk.py

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown

brown.words()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try renaming `nltk.py` to something else. I'm guessing the `import nltk` and `from nltk.corpus` is trying to import from your `nltk.py` file instead of the package. The reason it works when building the image is because your `nltk.py` file didn't exist yet, since it is mounted at runtime from the compose file.

Comment: Great. I guess that did the trick. Thank you! I'll post the final version

Answer (score 1):

> final Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV NLTK_DATA /usr/share/nltk_data

RUN pip install -U nltk
RUN pip install -U numpy
RUN python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/share/nltk_data all

EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /var/www

CMD [ "python", "/var/www/main.py" ]
```

> final docker-compose

```
nltk:
    build: docker/nltk
    container_name: nltk
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/nltk/var/www/main.py:/var/www/main.py
```